# How to import and export database from SQL SERVER to MYSQL SERVER vice versa in mono2.2 with gtksharp2.10 in ubuntu?

Tags: gtk, monodevelop, gtk-2, xml, c#

hy,

I am new guy in mono developer. i m using mono developer 2.2 with gtk#2.0.

i want develop desktop application in mono. i have to import database which having in SQL SERVER on web server and I want to import that data In my MYSQL Server with mono+Gtksharp (GTK# 2.10) than store it, And after some process in database, i want export database in MySQL server to sql server.

I don’t know to do this and I don’t have work with json and XML.

I don't want update system. My application is require by client in UBUNTU 10.4LTS.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks for giving your time for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, dump the SQL Server database as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391110/how-can-i-get-a-sql-dump-of-a-sql-server-2008-database). Then, import the database into MySQL using the mysql utility.

Comment: yes you r true but i dont know how to do in mono gtk# 2.0

Comment: can u have idea how to create dump in mono Gtk# or other IDE